# mongodb php MongoRegex slash

Tags: php, mongodb

hi i have some problom with mongodb MongoRegex and php driver
i have string pc/mobile;

i need to serach in db like this

```
$string  = "pc/mobile";
$query = array( "cat" => new MongoRegex('/'.$string.'/') );
$cursor = $account_cat->find($query)->limit(1);
$array = iterator_to_array($cursor,false);
```

i have tried

```
new MongoRegex('/'.$string.'/\')
```

and this

```
new MongoRegex('/'.$string.'/i')
```

which is working but i need not case sensitive.

can someone help? thanks

Comment: `new MongoRegex('/'.$string.'/\')` is typo, the backslash there escapes the closing quote which is for the encapsulation of the regex/delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a `/` in your pattern, you need to escape that when sending it to `MongoRegex`. For example:

```
$cat = new MongoRegex( '/' . addslashes( $string ) . '/' );
$query = array( "cat" => $cat );
```

But if you are just matching against a value, you should not need a regular expression.